# How Airflow DockerOperator send notification when Docker image creation error

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I want to send notification when Airflow DockerOperator can't create Docker image. Notification can be sent in case of DockerOperator execution errors using `on_failure_callback`.

To be more specific, I want to catch 2 errors.

1. private Docker repository is not running(10.11.12.13 is not running in example below)
2. execution server is not running(20.21.22.23:2345 is not running in example below)

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

def send_slack():
    print('send error message')

default_args = {
    'on_failure_callback': send_slack,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='45 * * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=420),
    concurrency=1,
    tags=['test']
) as dag:

    t = DockerOperator(
        task_id="test_operator",
        container_name="test_container",
        image=f"10.11.12.13/myapp:latest",
        force_pull=False,
        auto_remove=True,
        command = " python my_test.py ",
        docker_url="tcp://20.21.22.23:2375",
        cpus=1,
        mem_limit="1g",
        mount_tmp_dir=False
    )

    t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle the specific errors, you need to look at the code of the DockerOperator and create your own custom operator:

```
class MyCustomDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    ... # here implement any customisations
```

You can look at how the operator is implemented and override specific methods, catch specific exception and handle it in the way you see best for you.

And then - use MyCustomDockerOperator in your DAG. You can even add it to a shared util code if you want to use it in multiple DAGs.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516701/jarek-potiuk)'s answer, I implement very rough CustomOperator below.

```py
class MyCustomDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    def execute(self, context) -> Option[str]:
        try:
            super().execute(context)
        except AirflowException:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            raise AirflowException('something is wrong in creating docker image.') from e
```